# Changing values of data.frame where rowname == colname

Tags: r, dataframe

I wanted to set the value of each cell where the `rowname` and `colname` are identical to `-1`.

So this data frame:

```
      var1   var2   var3   var4   var5   var6 
var1     0      0      0      0      0      0
var2     0      0      0      0      0      0
var3     0      0      0      0      0      0
var4     0      0      0      0      0      0
var5     0      0      0      0      0      0
```

would change to this:

```
      var1   var2   var3   var4   var5   var6
var1    -1      0      0      0      0      0
var2     0     -1      0      0      0      0
var3     0      0     -1      0      0      0
var4     0      0      0     -1      0      0
var5     0      0      0      0     -1      0
```

What's the best way to perform this function?

Comment: `diag(df) <- -1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to find cells where the `rowname` matches the `colname` you could just use a simple `for` loop to loop through `rownames`, then use square bracket notation to find the appropriate cells:

```
for (x in rownames(df)) {
    df[x, x] <- -1
}

df
     var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6
var1   -1    0    0    0    0    0
var2    0   -1    0    0    0    0
var3    0    0   -1    0    0    0
var4    0    0    0   -1    0    0
var5    0    0    0    0   -1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @divibisan's answer, but using matrix character indexing:

```
m[cbind(rownames(m), rownames(m))] <- -1
```

Each row of the matrix `i = cbind(rownames(m), rownames(m))` denotes a pair {rowname, colname} identifying a position to assign to. See `?Extract` for details.